# How do I run cron per 40 millisecond in PHP

Tags: php, cron

I would like to run a cron every 40 milliseconds , I have tried following script for execute a cron file every 40 millisecond but It could not execute every 40 milliseconds .

```
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
    sleep(40);
    myFunction();
    define('LOGPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/TestCron/');
    error_log("\n\n---Cron Execution Time is  --".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." ------\n<br>", 3, LOGPATH."Val.log");
}


function myFunction(){
 /*Here my custom code */
}
```

I have also set below the line in cpanel

```
sleep 40; /usr/bin/env php /home/xxxx/public_html/xxx/testCront.php
```

Comment: _“If your task needs to run that frequently, cron is the wrong tool.”_ - https://serverfault.com/a/49085 (and that was regarding a 30 second interval only.)

Comment: The usual minimum interval you can get using the built-in functionality, is one minute. // Please go read [ask]. A question like this should start with a proper explanation, of what you need this for in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe, I want to execute my cron file every 40 miliseconds not per minutes

Comment: So, forget about cron. And keep your loop, but with [`usleep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usleep.php)

Comment: @mario, Can you please write a script in answer for me so I can check

Comment: _“I want to  […]”_ - we already know that, no point in repeating it. You were asked what the _purpose_ of this is supposed to be, what you need this _for_. (If you explain that, then people could maybe suggest alternatives.)

Comment: I agree, cron is the wrong tool for this as you are using it. In an ideal world, you'd instead probably write a service which you can find many tutorials for depending on your OS. If you want to keep it simple, however, you can keep your PHP script, switch it to `usleep`, and then run a cron task every once in a while to make sure it hasn't died using [`flock`](https://cjhaas.com/2020/10/16/flock-is-awesome/) or similar.

Comment: now i'm curious : what could you possibly want to do backend side with a 40ms interval ?